# Rodar um app em desenvolvimento em aparelho real prejudica o desempenho do mesmo?

Tags: android, desempenho

Estou receosa quanto a rodar meu app em desenvolvimento no meu aparelho. Alguém poderia me dizer se isso prejudica o desempenho, deixa grande quantidade de lixo, deixa portas abertas e vulneráveis nele?

Comment: Você é a programadora, vc dita o que seu software fará, em relação a lixo de memória vc deve saber como funciona o ciclo de vida dos aplicativos. aqui está um link http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922, existem várias informações no google e na propria api do android sobre  ciclo de vida e em relação a vulnerabilidades, digo denovo vc faz o app, vc deve saber o que está codando, e o android é mt rigoroso em relação a acessos restritos, vc sempre tem que informar no manifest.xml recursos que vc vai utilizar, ex. camera, acesso sd, net, etc.

Comment: Muito obrigada, Juarez ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

À princípio não prejudica em nada diretamente. Mas...

Sua preocupação faz sentido, se o aplicativo tiver problemas ele pode no mínimo deixar o aparelho vulnerável se ele permite de alguma forma ser acessado externamente de forma direta ou, mais raramente, indiretamente.

Note que este risco não é tão grande assim. E de uma maneira geral os aplicativos não podem fazer grandes estragos como é possível em um computador com mais liberdade de ação dos aplicativos (dentro da API tradicional). Nada poderá acessar o aplicativo tão facilmente. E até onde eu sei a imensa maioria dos aplicativos desenvolvidos pouco expõem a acesso externo arbitrário.

Então é bom saber que não há garantias mas também não precisa ter grande preocupação que qualquer coisinha errada que seja feita gerará um grande problema. Em geral tecnologias mais avançadas é que darão mais chances para vulnerabilidades. Se vai usar coisas mais avançadas é claro que precisa dominar o seu uso. Normalmente eu diria que o domínio é necessário para fazer qualquer coisa em software, mas já vi que a tendência atual é todo mundo sair fazendo o que não conhece sem muita preocupação com riscos.

É evidente que alguns cuidados precisam ser tomados, é preciso ficar com olho mais atento a todo ciclo de uso do aplicativo enquanto ele está em testes.

Nem vou tentar dizer que existem técnicas de monitoramento do aplicativo para entender tudo o que está ocorrendo com ele. Isto por si só já é uma técnica avançada.

Imagino que vá usar Java para desenvolver (pense em [Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101)). Esta é uma linguagem que ajuda a não cometer uma série de erros e deixar o aplicativo vulnerável de várias formas. Mas não faz milagre, se não usar técnicas adequadas pode comprometer a segurança.

Mas saiba que os aplicativos para esta plataforma normalmente são ativos, ou seja, eles é que tomam a ação para fora. Raramente eles deixam fonte externa tomar ações. Então isto já ajuda bastante. Claro que você pode liberar acesso externo acidentalmente. Mas é bem difícil fazer isto. Muitas vezes é difícil fazer querendo, imagina sem querer.

## Conclusão

- O risco existe mas ele é pequeno, em geral bem pequeno.
- Tenha atenção, estude para entender o que está fazendo.
- Não deixe o aplicativo em teste rodando sem um monitoramento até ter confiança que nada está errado.
- Evite usar o que não conhece o suficiente e peça ajuda quando precisar.
- Sabendo que há riscos mínimos, garanta que não há dados críticos e que não podem ser perdidos, como por exemplo, senhas de acesso à recursos internos ou externos.

Comment: Muito bem explicado! Obrigada pela resposta, bigown! ;)