# O que é Kotlin?

Tags: característica-linguagem, kotlin

Tenho ouvido falar muito de **Kotlin**.

O que é isso?  É uma linguagem de programação? Se sim: Quais as principais características? Posso programar em qualquer sistema operacional? E executar? Como funcionam os tipos nela?

Não quero saber tudo, mas uma informação básica sobre o que é isso.

Comment: E eu só gostaria de saber como que se pronuncia isso.

Comment: [Aparentemente é assim como lemos em português: "**_có-tlin_**".](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-correct-english-pronunciation-of-kotlin/20500)

Comment: Rela: [Quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205914/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-kotlin-e-java)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Uma linguagem maravilhosa, é só isso que eu tenho pra dizer :P

Ok, deixando a brincadeira de lado, é uma linguagem criada pela JetBrains, dona de um IDE que muitos consideram o que tem de melhor no mercado, como o [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), e o do [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), que muitos consideram um *plugin* indispensável para o Visual Studio, entre outros bons produtos.

Ao que tudo indica eles a criaram para ter uma ferramenta melhor para desenvolver seus próprios produtos. Mais ainda, a ideia original era ter uma linguagem que gera *bytecodes* para a JVM e para o [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), assim muito do código usado em produto poderia ser reaproveitado em outro. Hoje eles desenvolvem basicamente em Java, e replicam muito código em C# para o Resharper (agora tem o [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) que é um IDE para .NET inteiro deles, mas roda com JVM).

Também usam como alvo o JavaScript, talvez para ter IDE web em breve. Talvez foquem em [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) no futuro. De fato tem acontecido ao longo do tempo.

Já estão criando código nativo que não depende da JVM.

Com o tempo desistiram da ideia de gerar código para o [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101). Sei lá se retomarão. Perceberam que era complicado conciliar uma boa linguagem com esses dois alvos, não só pelo *runtime*, mas por toda biblioteca de cada plataforma. E provavelmente teria poucos benefícios. Não sei se não estão criando ou até já usando experimentalmente algum conversor de Kotlin para C# ou até de Java para C# para facilitar o desenvolvimento.

Mas ainda era útil ter uma linguagem melhor que Java. Muitas pessoas criticam a linguagem da Oracle. Eles queriam um *feel* mais próximo do C#, e quem sabe alguma coisa até melhor, e [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) servia bem a isso. Queriam algo que rodasse na JVM, usasse toda JEE e se comunicasse com todo código que eles já possuíam em Java, mas que fosse mais agradável de desenvolver, que desse mais produtividade e robustez. Quem vislumbraram ter mais um produto na sua linha também.

Eles partiram do Java, mas muito da linguagem fora inspirada no C# e Scala, dando um tom mais funcional, mas ainda com força no imperativo que é algo que a maioria dos programadores estão acostumados. Se inspiraram também em outras linguagens, tentaram deixar o código mais limpo, como Python faz.

Recentemente [a Google oficializou a linguagem para uso no Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/index.html), e há muita empolgação no seu uso. Com isso muita gente acha que será mais palatável programar em cima de uma JVM.

> Posso programar em qualquer sistema operacional? E executar?

Pode programar onde tiver uma infraestrutura da JVM, melhor ainda se tiver um IDE para Kotlin, o que é mais ou menos onde tem uma JVM. Claro que você não vai rodar um IDE no Android.

Em tese roda em qualquer lugar onde tenha uma JVM. Essas coisas nunca são 100% garantidas, mas basicamente é isso, salvo as incompatibilidades específicas, JVM é que determina onde pode rodar. Também pode rodar onde tenha JavaScript implementado, desde que gere código para isto. Não sei se esta plataforma está bem suportada.

Agora ficou um pouco melhor com a possibilidade de gerar executável nativo. Ainda não é adequada para criar um OS, mas não é um absurdo tão grande quanto era antes.

> Quais as principais características?

- Ela interopera muito bem com Java. Também é bem compatível com quase tudo existente.
- Adota muito da programação funcional mas ainda em estilo imperativo e mantendo a força da orientação a objeto.
- Possui *pattern matching*.
- Facilidades para fazer algo semelhante ao LINQ e não é só métodos de extensão. Também possui implementação padrão em interfaces, como o Java 8, e o C# 8.
- Sintaxe simplificada e intuitiva, evita o uso do `;` por exemplo, nada de verborragia.
- Permite propriedades delegadas que é melhor que eventos e gambiarras para fazer a propriedade ser observável.
- Declara o tipo da variável opcionalmente no lugar certo, não copiaram C :P
- Possui blocos atômicos para transações em memória que precisam ocorrer tudo ou nada sem intervenção externa.
- Ela incentiva o uso de DSLs. Fazer algo nela mesma se parecendo com XAML ou algo assim é relativamente simples.
- Trabalha nativamente com objetos *singleton*.
- Permite delegação de classe.
- Melhor sistema de anotação.
- Alias de tipo, como C# faz com `using`.
- Algumas coisas que tem no Java é melhor implementado em Kotlin.
- Usa interpolação de *string*.
- Em geral as construções da linguagem funcionam como expressões.
- Não tem exceções checadas. TYG.
- Usa co-rotinas.
- E muito mais, claro.

Veja mais em [outra pergunta sobre ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205914/101).

> Como funcionam os tipos nela?

Muito parecido com Java, mas tem algumas coisas mais específicas. Tenta puxar um pouco para o C# e adota algumas coisas de Scala e outras linguagens funcionais.

- Tudo deriva de `Any`, como ocorre em C#, ao contrário do Java que vende a ideia que tudo é objeto, mas não é. Na verdade C# tem tipos que não derivam de `object`, mas funciona à parte.
- Os tipos não são nulos a não ser que mande ser, e isto por si só já vale a linguagem. C# 8 tem isso também onde falta. Existem mecanismos pra lidar melhor quando quer um tipo anulável.
- Privilegia objetos imutáveis por padrão, deixando o programador escolher que seja mutável.
- Tem facilidades como sobrecarga de operadores, propriedades, indexadores, coerções, etc. igual ao C#
- Os genéricos são de verdade, mesmo a JVM não ajudando, é parecido com C#, mas também tem algumas coisas do Java.
- Possui tipos de dados algébricos ([ADTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type)) que eu adoraria que C# tivesse. Isso veio de Scala.
- Existem as classes de dados, semelhante aos registros que terão no C#.
- As *lambdas* são tipadas diretamente na linguagem, diferente de C# que ainda parece meio gambiarra usando tipos de apoio até na sintaxe.
- Tem função *inline* que é uma otimização entre a função normal e a *lambda*.
- Ainda que não totalmente ligado à tipagem, ela não privilegia exceções, usa um `Maybe` por exemplo.
- Apesar de se basear no JEE, possui muitos tipos melhores que substituem o que se usa em Java. Ainda é possível usar os tipos do Java para compatibilidade. Não é o ideal, mas é que tem pra hoje.
- É possível criar um tipo dinâmico, como em C# (mas é limitado ao alvo JS).
- Tem `Unit` que é melhor que `void`, e tem `Nothing` que é melhor que `null`, e não é só o nome não, a semântica é mais adequada.
- Tem *ranges*.
- Evita *boxing* sem necessidade.
- Falta `structs`, mas quem sabe venha junto com Java 10.

## Conclusão

Os desenvolvedores de Kotlin são muito bons. Não são um Anders Hejlsberg, mas não são aloprados, voluntariosos fazendo maluquices sem sentido, não é uma linguagem que mostrará problemas aos montes com tempo.

Eu ainda prefiro C# entre as linguagens existentes, mas se eu tiver que trabalhar com JVM, Kotlin seria minha escolha.

- [Página oficial](https://kotlinlang.org/)
- [SO Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170605082216/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/kotlin/topics) arquivado

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Texto complementar: http://www.androidpro.com.br/kotlin/

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada superficial e gostei. Estranhei que pra fazer algo tão simples quanto repetir uma coisa x vezes eu preciso declarar um array de x posições (mesmo que vazio, porque Kotlin só tem laço for sobre enumeráveis), mas de resto ela parece ser bem melhor que Java mesmo.

Comment: @Renan acho que não é isso não, deve ter passado a impressão errada, ela tem *range* que não é *array*.

Comment: @bigown vi agora. `for (i in 1..10)`. Agora, com o `for` tradicional eu fazia mágica com datas (i.e.: `for (DateTime data = DateTime.Today; data < outraData; data = data.AddDays(1)) {...}`. Dá pra fazer com range?

Comment: @Renan acho que não, eu sinto falta de `for` normal, acho uma babaquice dessas linguagens novas, odeio linguagem que quer proteger o programador de fazer o que ele saber fazer bem, a proteção deve ser naquelas coisas que o programador erra sem querer, não no que erra porque não quer estudar.

Comment: @bigown quem sabe na próxima versão Kotlin não acaba suportando o `for` tradicional.

Comment: @Renan me lembro que isso foi discutido e deliberado. Swift fez pior, tinha, e deixou de ter :D

Comment: @Maniero na conclusão o link **SO Docs** está fora do ar.. você poderia ajustar isso?

Comment: @FernandoSouza feito!

Comment: Dá pra fazer o `for` igual do java no kotlin desta forma: `for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) { ... }`

Comment: @EduardoDornel você acabou de mostrar que não dá, apenas que é possível ter um índice, mas com um custo extra, o `for` bruto é justamente não ter que lidar com nada extra, principalmente com uma abstração extra.