# Kotlin para criação e APIs: serve somente para Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Vi algumas funcionalidades oferecidas pela ferramenta Kotlin, ainda mais em se tratando em economizar linhas de código e verbosidade gerado no Java.

Como é a ferramenta para gerar serviços e serem consumidas por aplicações Web? Como o Angular 2+, por exemplo... A linguagem teria esse suporte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221905/101) é uma linguagem como outra qualquer. Ela não tem qualquer vinculação com tecnologia específica e é capaz de executar qualquer coisa. É exceção qualquer linguagem que tenha limitações quanto ao uso.

Claro, o suporte de bibliotecas e ferramentas extras sempre varia de linguagem para linguagem. Kotlin pode ser usada como *backend* web sem problemas, porém não há um suporte tão bom quanto outras soluções, até por ter uma comunidade, hoje, ainda pequena. Porém quase tudo que serve para Java serve para ela em maior ou menor grau, então o suporte não é tão pequeno assim.

Angular é uma tecnologia de *frontend* (até já vi gente usando no *backend*, mas não da forma normal). O suporte em *browsers* para outras linguagens além do JavaScript é recente. Kotlin até tem um modo de geração de JavaScript, mas quando ela puder gerar código próprio ficará mais poderosa. Em qualquer caso é possível integrar com Angular, mas fará pouco sentido, e terá pouca compatibilidade. Será mais interessante ter um *framework* dela para substituir o Angular no navegador. Mas claro, se ela for usada no *backend*, pode se comunicar sem problemas com o cliente rodando Angular, são coisas completamente distintas que se comunicam por protocolos universais.

Comment: Legal... estou buscando encontrar um cenário para um projeto novo que estou desenvolvendo... Na verdade, já tenho muita manha com Js e Ts, e estou me integrando mais próximo ao Java, porém, é extremamente verboso.
Eu dei uma olhada no Groovy tbm, achei interessante!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é perfeitamente possível construir seu backend com Kotlin.

Uma das grandes prioridades do Kotlin é oferecer [interoperabilidade](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) com o Java. Então, praticamente todas bibliotecas / frameworks que você usaria para construir seu backend em Java podem ser usados com Kotlin.

Um grande exemplo hoje é o [Spring](https://spring.io/), um dos maiores frameworks web pra Java, que já oferece [suporte ao Kotlin há mais de dois anos](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/developing-spring-boot-applications-with-kotlin).